# PosgreSQL: Четырехтабличный SQL запрос с сортировкой по максимальному количеству

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql, запрос-в-запросе

Схема базы данных (posgresql):

```
Book(id, title, student_id)
Student(id, name, last_name, e_mail)
Teacher(id, name, last_name, e_mail, subject)
Groups(student_id, teacher_id)
```

Выбрать `Teacher` у которых самое большое количество `Book` у всех его `Student`. Отсортировать по количеству в порядке убывания. Выглядеть должно так:

```
Teacher’s last_name | Book’s quantity   
Petrov              |      9  
Ivanov              |      5
```

Мой запрос возвращает только Фамилии учителей...

```
SELECT
  Teacher.last_name 
FROM
  Teacher 
WHERE
  EXISTS (
    SELECT
      Groups.teacher_id
    FROM
      Groups
    WHERE
      EXISTS (
        SELECT
          Book.student_id, COUNT(student_id) AS cnt
        FROM
          Book
        GROUP BY
          student_id
        ORDER BY
          cnt DESC))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно поступить следующим образом

```
SELECT
  t.name AS name,
  t.last_name AS last_name,
  COUNT(b.id) AS total
FROM
  Teacher AS t
JOIN
  Groups AS g
ON
  t.id = g.teacher_id
JOIN
  Student AS s
ON
  s.id = g.student_id
JOIN
  Book AS b
ON
  s.id = b.student_id
GROUP BY
  t.name, t.last_name
ORDER BY
  total DESC;
```

Comment: Благодарен Вам!